# There are a problem with one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, database-design, one-to-many

There are one to many relationship between Authors and Articles

Here is my models

```
    public class Authors
{
    [Key]
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public List<Articles> Articles { get; set; }
}

    public class Articles
{
    [Key]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Article { get; set; }
    public int Hit { get; set; }
    public Authors Authors { get; set; }
}
```

and ArticleCreate controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> 
ArticleCreate([Bind("ArticleId,AuthorId,Date,Active,Title,Article,Hit")] Articles articles)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(articles);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(ArticlesIndex));
        }
        return View(articles);
    }
```

I saw a new column named as AuthorsAuthorId in Articles table. When I try to add new Article with ArticleCreate controller, that AuthorsAuthorId column was null. AuthorId column already exists in the Articles table and I can see AuthorId value in here. When I manually added a value in AuthorsAuthorId, that works fine. But I can not adding with controller action..

I will be grateful for your helps ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the annotation `[ForeignKey("Authors")]` on your **AuthorId** field, in **Articles**.

Since your table is named **Authors**, but your foreign key is named **AuthorId** (note the pluralization) EF cannot infer automatically that this is your foreign key.